Using Entra ID for service-to-service auth - getting around the token cache issue
We are thinking about using Microsoft Entra ID for service-to-service authentication and authorization. All our services are provisioned with a managed identity and not having to protect any credentials is appealing.
However, there is a limitation when it comes to using managed identities for authorization. In particular:

Managed identity tokens on the other hand are cached by the underlying Azure infrastructure for performance and resiliency purposes: the back-end services for managed identities maintain a cache per resource URI for around 24 hours. This means that it can take several hours for changes to a managed identity's group or role membership to take effect. Today, it is not possible to force a managed identity's token to be refreshed before its expiry. If you change a managed identity’s group or role membership to add or remove permissions, you may therefore need to wait several hours for the Azure resource using the identity to have the correct access.

There certainly are workarounds, like each service periodically fetching the role assignments directly using the Graph API where the changes are visible immediately, but those bring additional complexity and increase the security surface of the system.
Those using Entra ID for service-to-service auth with managed identities, how do you deal with the token cache problem?

you could try to reduce the access token lifetime, from like the default 65 minutes down to like 5 minutes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes

Thank you @ToreNestenius, I will try that, though the parent page states that We currently don't support configuring the token lifetimes for managed identity service principals..

I verified that the token lifetime policies do not apply to tokens issued to managed identities, unfortunately. The token lifetime is still 24 hours, 5 minutes.
